# OpenCV Structured Light getProjPixel() example

Tags: java, android, opencv, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to recreate the structure light functions by following the structured light Graycode tutorials on OpenCv for Unity (it's a port of OpenCV java)

https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/dc/da9/tutorial_decode_graycode_pattern.html

The tutorials seem straightforward, but I think they may be out of date now. For instance, there is no more "decode" function in the Graycode part of the API
https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/dec/classcv_1_1structured__light_1_1GrayCodePattern.html

```
Mat disparityMap;
bool decoded = graycode->decode(captured_pattern, disparityMap, blackImages, whiteImages,
                                structured_light::DECODE_3D_UNDERWORLD);
```

Instead i think i might need to use getProjPixel() instead somehow? I can't find any other examples using this online thought.

This was my rough thought of maybe how to use it

```
for(int x = 0; x < 1920; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < 1080; y++)
            {
                Point thepoint= new Point(-1,-1);
                grayCode.getProjPixel(photosCam1, x, y, thepoint );
                projPix.Add(thepoint);
            }

        }
```

But i don't totally know what i would do next to get a pointcloud (and ultimately a mesh for unity) from this, or if i am even going the right direction

Comment: and i can confirm now that if i run that code, it just crashes

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like the answer is just that the Java port of OpenCV is incomplete when it comes to the structure light module. So there basically is no way to actually decode the captured images for java (or the subsequent ports to unity)

https://answers.opencv.org/question/222527/structured-light-module-missing-decode-function/?comment=222534#post-id-222534

too bad!